# how to calculate polygon area using field calculator QGIS?

Tags: area

I am trying to calculate the areas of some polygons and i want to use the field calculator to measure the area. The result i got using this method is different from using the QGIS measurement tool. I am confused on which is correct. How can i do this correctly?
Also is it possible to change the measurement unit of the field calculator to give result in meter square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate area with field calculator by `$area` expression, your result will depend on the projection of your shapefile.
Ex. if your projection is EPSG:4326 you will get an area in degrees. If you want meters, you need to reproject your shapefile to another projection (metric).